# High HTTP latency with PM2

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, pm2

I have a NestJS application running in docker with PM2 and it's extremely slow although it consumes very little resources. The reason is definitely not the traffic as there is nearly no traffic. When looking into PM2 Monitoring I see that the HTTP Latency is extremely high.

When running the same application locally I can't see any of this issues.

This is a snapshot of one of the clusters in PM2.

│ Heap Size                                          106.32 MiB  │
│ Heap Usage                                            86.07 %  │
│ Used Heap Size                                      91.51 MiB  │
│ Active requests                                             0  │
│ Active handles                                             16  │
│ Event Loop Latency                                    0.61 ms  │
│ Event Loop Latency p95                                1.59 ms  │
│ HTTP Mean Latency                                        2 ms  │
│ HTTP P95 Latency                                      9752 ms  │
│ HTTP                                                0 req/min  │

Any ideas what I can change in the configuration or how I can investigate into this issue? I haven't found anything on this topic anywhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this as i can see you have a http p95 latency of 9752 ms which doesn't sound good to me. I am also experiencing same in my express server.

Answer (score -2):

You can delete that app and restart, `pm2 delete app` and `pm2 start index.js`. This form will clear that latency. This has happened with my application

Comment: It will clear the logs, but it will not help against actual slow response times